# CURL will not display if POST enable

Tags: php, curl, cross-domain

I have this code that will login to an application here : https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/login.php

```
//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

$loginUrl = 'https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/login.php';

// what post fields?
$fields = array(
   '__CSRFToken__' => 'd1ab4d40f5dc51362b43ac87322a4b83a151ee62',
   'luser' => 'myname@flurred.com',
   'lpasswd' => '123456'
);

// build the urlencoded data
$postvars = http_build_query($fields);

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($data); //display output


// get cookies
$pattern = "/OSTSESSID=([a-z0-9]{26});/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);

echo $cookie = 'OSTSESSID='.$matches[1][0];
```

However I'm not getting html output of the page but I do get this output:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 05:07:16 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34 Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=16b08fd848f46509ca83e20bb8c8a1c0; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 05:07:17 GMT; path=/osTicket/; domain=demos6.softaculous.com; secure Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Location: index.php Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

)
OSTSESSID=
```

but If I disable curl POST such as below:

```
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
```

I will get html output with forms. I was expecting to get forms with error code because I'm using wrong `CSRF token`, `email` and `password` but for some reason I'm only getting empty array output.

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have my own cookie routine.  I use some additional curl options in case of problems.  Did not really have any problems.

I think your regex expression is incorrect.

The cookie in the response header was (as shown in Results below):

```
'OSTSESSID' => '=b41427a694c56b74ca5573bf9c16d2df',
```

### PHP

```
 header('Content-Type:text/plain');
 $ch = curl_init();
$loginUrl = 'https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/login.php';

// what post fields?
$fields = array(
   '__CSRFToken__' => 'd1ab4d40f5dc51362b43ac87322a4b83a151ee62',
   'luser' => 'myname@flurred.com',
   'lpasswd' => '123456'
);

// build the urlencoded data
$postvars = http_build_query($fields);

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)){
$data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $responseheader = substr($data,0,$skip);
//  $data = substr($data,$skip);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $info = var_export($info,true);
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = stripos($responseheader,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($responseheader,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($responseheader,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;
    $export = var_export($cookies,true);
  }
  $seperator = "\n##################################################\n";
  echo $responseheader . $seperator . $export . $seperator . $info . $seperator . $data;
}
```

### Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 05:44:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=3b1f0ed44d8412514dcbb620ecb7ae87; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 05:44:27 GMT; path=/osTicket/; domain=demos6.softaculous.com; secure
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: index.php
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 05:44:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=b41427a694c56b74ca5573bf9c16d2df; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 05:44:28 GMT; path=/osTicket/; domain=demos6.softaculous.com; secure
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 4936
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


##################################################
array (
  'OSTSESSID' => '=b41427a694c56b74ca5573bf9c16d2df',
)
##################################################
array (
  'url' => 'https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/index.php',
  'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'http_code' => 200,
  'header_size' => 992,
  'request_size' => 518,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 1,
  'total_time' => 1.650162,
  'namelookup_time' => 3.3E-5,
  'connect_time' => 0.049946,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0.116732,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 4936,
  'speed_download' => 2991,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => 4936,
  'upload_content_length' => -1,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0.892359,
  'redirect_time' => 0.757793,
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'redirect_url' => '',
  'request_header' => 'GET /osTicket/index.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)
Host: demos6.softaculous.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip

',
)
##################################################
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 05:44:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=3b1f0ed44d8412514dcbb620ecb7ae87; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 05:44:27 GMT; path=/osTicket/; domain=demos6.softaculous.com; secure
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: index.php
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 05:44:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=b41427a694c56b74ca5573bf9c16d2df; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 05:44:28 GMT; path=/osTicket/; domain=demos6.softaculous.com; secure
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 4936
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>osTicket :: Support Ticket System</title>
    <meta name="description" content="customer support platform">
    <meta name="keywords" content="osTicket, Customer support system, support ticket system">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/osticket.css?4be5782" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/assets/default/css/theme.css?4be5782" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/assets/default/css/print.css?4be5782" media="print">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/scp/css/typeahead.css"
         media="screen" />
    <link type="text/css" href="/osTicket/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/thread.css?4be5782" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/redactor.css?4be5782" media="screen">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/font-awesome.min.css?4be5782">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/flags.css?4be5782">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/rtl.css?4be5782"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script src="/osTicket/js/osticket.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/filedrop.field.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/jquery.multiselect.min.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script src="/osTicket/scp/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/redactor.min.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/redactor-osticket.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/redactor-fonts.js?4be5782"></script>

    <meta name="csrf_token" content="1a84c2f1eb895ab07f090f90eb4b3cf81f7f6e05" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="pull-right flush-right">
            <p>
                                 Guest User |                     <a href="/osTicket/login.php">Sign In</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            </div>
            <a class="pull-left" id="logo" href="/osTicket/index.php"
            title="Support Center">
                <span class="valign-helper"></span>
                <img src="/osTicket/logo.php" border=0 alt="osTicket :: Support Ticket System">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
                <ul id="nav" class="flush-left">
            <li><a class="active home" href="/osTicket/index.php">Support Center Home</a></li>
<li><a class=" new" href="/osTicket/open.php">Open a New Ticket</a></li>
<li><a class=" status" href="/osTicket/view.php">Check Ticket Status</a></li>
        </ul>
                <div id="content">

         <div id="landing_page">
    <h1>Welcome to the Support Center</h1> <p> In order to streamline support requests and better serve you, we utilize a support ticket system. Every support request is assigned a unique ticket number which you can use to track the progress and responses online. For your reference we provide complete archives and history of all your support requests. A valid email address is required to submit a ticket. </p>    <div id="new_ticket" class="pull-left">
        <h3>Open a New Ticket</h3>
        <br>
        <div>Please provide as much detail as possible so we can best assist you. To update a previously submitted ticket, please login.</div>
    </div>

    <div id="check_status" class="pull-right">
        <h3>Check Ticket Status</h3>
        <br>
        <div>We provide archives and history of all your current and past support requests complete with responses.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="front-page-button pull-left">
        <p>
            <a href="open.php" class="green button">Open a New Ticket</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="front-page-button pull-right">
        <p>
            <a href="view.php" class="blue button">Check Ticket Status</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 osTicket :: Support Ticket System - All rights reserved.</p>
        <a id="poweredBy" href="http://osticket.com" target="_blank">Helpdesk software - powered by osTicket</a>
    </div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="loading">
    <h4>Please Wait!</h4>
    <p>Please wait... it will take a second!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Without Follow

Here I set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to false.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

This requires me to do the redirect myself.  I get the cookie from the first request and use it in the second.

The second request is a GET and the cookie is the confirmation that the first request was completed.

The `$seperator` serves two purpose, one to make it easier to find the sections of data, and two, to show that code completed and indicate what values, if any are missing.

```
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/login.php';

$fields = array(
   '__CSRFToken__' => 'd1ab4d40f5dc51362b43ac87322a4b83a151ee62',
   'luser' => 'myname@flurred.com',
   'lpasswd' => '123456'
);
$postvars = http_build_query($fields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)){
$data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $responseheader = substr($data,0,$skip);
//  $data = substr($data,$skip);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $info = var_export($info,true);
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = stripos($responseheader,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($responseheader,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($responseheader,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;
    $export = var_export($cookies,true);
  }
}
  $seperator = "\n##################################################\n";
  echo $responseheader . $seperator . $export . $seperator . $info . $seperator . $data;
$responseheader = '';
$info = ''; 
$data = ''; 
$export = ''; 
     $cookie = '';
     $head = '';
     $delim = '';
     foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
       $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
       $delim = '; ';
     }


$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/index.php';
echo  $seperator . $url . $seperator ;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
$data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $responseheader = substr($data,0,$skip);
//  $data = substr($data,$skip);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $info = var_export($info,true);
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = stripos($responseheader,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($responseheader,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($responseheader,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;
    $export = var_export($cookies,true);
  }
}
echo $responseheader . $seperator . $export . $seperator . $info . $seperator . $data;
```

### Result

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 06:47:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=ced776fb9a5d70a00cceec67fb8e4212; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 06:47:21 GMT; path=/osTicket/; domain=demos6.softaculous.com; secure
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: index.php
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8


##################################################
array (
  'OSTSESSID' => '=ced776fb9a5d70a00cceec67fb8e4212',
)
##################################################
array (
  'url' => 'https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/login.php',
  'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'http_code' => 302,
  'header_size' => 511,
  'request_size' => 342,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 1.169197,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.063324,
  'connect_time' => 0.113847,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0.240441,
  'size_upload' => 96,
  'size_download' => 13,
  'speed_download' => 11,
  'speed_upload' => 82,
  'download_content_length' => -1,
  'upload_content_length' => 96,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0.832286,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'redirect_url' => 'https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/index.php',
  'request_header' => 'POST /osTicket/login.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)
Host: demos6.softaculous.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Content-Length: 96
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

',
)
##################################################
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 06:47:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=ced776fb9a5d70a00cceec67fb8e4212; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 06:47:21 GMT; path=/osTicket/; domain=demos6.softaculous.com; secure
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: index.php
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html></html>
```

**second request**

```
##################################################
https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/index.php
##################################################
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 06:47:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 4936
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


##################################################

##################################################
array (
  'url' => 'https://demos6.softaculous.com/osTicket/index.php',
  'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'http_code' => 200,
  'header_size' => 330,
  'request_size' => 228,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 0.916081,
  'namelookup_time' => 3.3E-5,
  'connect_time' => 0.050004,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0.175644,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 4936,
  'speed_download' => 5388,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => 4936,
  'upload_content_length' => -1,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0.916071,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
```

**Cookie was sent**

Request Header:

```
  'redirect_url' => '',
  'request_header' => 'GET /osTicket/index.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)
Host: demos6.softaculous.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Cookie: OSTSESSID=ced776fb9a5d70a00cceec67fb8e4212

',
)
```

.

```
##################################################
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 06:47:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 4936
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>osTicket :: Support Ticket System</title>
    <meta name="description" content="customer support platform">
    <meta name="keywords" content="osTicket, Customer support system, support ticket system">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/osticket.css?4be5782" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/assets/default/css/theme.css?4be5782" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/assets/default/css/print.css?4be5782" media="print">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/scp/css/typeahead.css"
         media="screen" />
    <link type="text/css" href="/osTicket/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/thread.css?4be5782" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/redactor.css?4be5782" media="screen">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/font-awesome.min.css?4be5782">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/flags.css?4be5782">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/osTicket/css/rtl.css?4be5782"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script src="/osTicket/js/osticket.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/filedrop.field.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/jquery.multiselect.min.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script src="/osTicket/scp/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/redactor.min.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/redactor-osticket.js?4be5782"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/osTicket/js/redactor-fonts.js?4be5782"></script>

    <meta name="csrf_token" content="dc9ebdbeae677f8bb76f405d9bd5d5cedd6c40b2" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="pull-right flush-right">
            <p>
                                 Guest User |                     <a href="/osTicket/login.php">Sign In</a>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            </div>
            <a class="pull-left" id="logo" href="/osTicket/index.php"
            title="Support Center">
                <span class="valign-helper"></span>
                <img src="/osTicket/logo.php" border=0 alt="osTicket :: Support Ticket System">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
                <ul id="nav" class="flush-left">
            <li><a class="active home" href="/osTicket/index.php">Support Center Home</a></li>
<li><a class=" new" href="/osTicket/open.php">Open a New Ticket</a></li>
<li><a class=" status" href="/osTicket/view.php">Check Ticket Status</a></li>
        </ul>
                <div id="content">

         <div id="landing_page">
    <h1>Welcome to the Support Center</h1> <p> In order to streamline support requests and better serve you, we utilize a support ticket system. Every support request is assigned a unique ticket number which you can use to track the progress and responses online. For your reference we provide complete archives and history of all your support requests. A valid email address is required to submit a ticket. </p>    <div id="new_ticket" class="pull-left">
        <h3>Open a New Ticket</h3>
        <br>
        <div>Please provide as much detail as possible so we can best assist you. To update a previously submitted ticket, please login.</div>
    </div>

    <div id="check_status" class="pull-right">
        <h3>Check Ticket Status</h3>
        <br>
        <div>We provide archives and history of all your current and past support requests complete with responses.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="front-page-button pull-left">
        <p>
            <a href="open.php" class="green button">Open a New Ticket</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="front-page-button pull-right">
        <p>
            <a href="view.php" class="blue button">Check Ticket Status</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 osTicket :: Support Ticket System - All rights reserved.</p>
        <a id="poweredBy" href="http://osticket.com" target="_blank">Helpdesk software - powered by osTicket</a>
    </div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="loading">
    <h4>Please Wait!</h4>
    <p>Please wait... it will take a second!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately both solution does not work for me. Here's the output of `1st solution`: http://pastebin.com/iQb7fka5 and here's `Without Follow` : http://pastebin.com/z449G9Kj I'm not sure what I did wrong. I copy and paste to make sure I make no mistake. I really appreciate your help btw.

Comment: It appears on your first link the `FOLLOWLOCATION` was false as it only got the 302 redirect. The 2nd you definitely made a mistake.  No matter what the second request even if it failed `$seperator`  would have echoed. It looks like you only copied the first half of the code.  I will update and take out the comments in the No Follow code.

Comment: It appears the problem was with `https`. I have solved it by adding this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);` Thanks for your help.